# Why do car 12V and USB power outlets shut off when the car is off?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, automotive

Just out of curiosity, I'm wondering why "cigarette lighter style" 12-volt and USB power outlets provide no power when the car is off in most cars. Is it because the electrical system that connects to those outlets is running off the alternator and not the battery?

Comment: what is a 'car charger'? I can't guess from the context of your question. My car charger provides power, when I plug it into the wall to charge my car, whether the car is on or off!

Comment: It's the charger that you plug into a cigarette lighter of your vehicle to provide power to a portable electronic device.

Comment: One good reason is to prevent kids playing with the cigarette lighter while unattended (yes, I know) in the car.

Answer (score 5):

In most cars, the cigarette lighter socket is on the accessory circuit and is only active when the key is in the accessory or run positions.

Some cars have it always live.

Answer (score 5):

I would suspect that it's done to stop you leaving something charging while you go shopping then coming back to find you don't have enough battery power to start the car.  A former car of mine had the cigarette lighter fused at 10A, which can drain a 35AH battery surprisingly quickly.

Answer (score 3):

It's an aesthetic choice by the designer.

I've seen cars go either way, and older cars in particular like to leave it available 24x7. That was important back then, when the "killer app" for those outlets was running a cigarette lighter, something you'd often use while sitting in the car not driving.

The problem *today* with leaving them powered at all times is that people will leave things plugged in at all times.  Some things like device chargers, sat navs ("GPS navigators"), dash cams and the like can take a considerable amount of current, and leave you with a dead battery.

What's more, even if they only draw the battery down 50% or so, *doing that is really bad for lead-acid batteries, particularly car starting batteries*.  All lead-acids take damage when discharged more than 30% or so, but for batteries optimized for engine starting, it is worse.  So if they did allow limited drawdown, it would cause premature battery failure and increased warranty claims.

Of course EV's change the calculus completely. Their 12V lead-acid battery (for accessories) is not a starting battery, and the car could simply keep it topped up from the main propulsion battery.  Sat nav's and dash cams would take months to drain an EV battery, so it wouldn't be an issue if those were left on.  In fact, Teslas do run the dash cams 24x7.

Comment: Anecdotally, I was once stranded with a full EV propulsion battery because the 12 V lead-acid battery couldn't hold a charge. Hyundai's engineers weren't bright enough to predict that one, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

This is done deliberately by the OEMs. They have to keep the parasitic power at a minimum so the car will start after a defined time such as sitting at the airport for two weeks. The parasitic power is taken into account in the calculation of the battery size. Any additional load will upset this calculation and make it invalid. Many of us older travelers remember the parking lots especially in cold areas have a vehicle drive around jumping customers cars to get them started as the batteries were drained. A common cause was the GPS plugged into the "cigar lighter socket".